# Настройка прав доступа к примонтированному каталогу Docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, artisan

Я пытаюсь развернуть laravel в докер контейнере. У меня следующий Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV HOST_IP=172.17.0.1
ENV PHP_VER=7.2
#Change the default PHP Version as it is updated

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=nonintercative apt update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install apache2 -y
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install php \
                                            php-cli \
                                            php-common \
                                            php-json \
                                            php-mysql \
                                            php-zip \
                                            php-xml \
                                            php-pgsql \
                                            php-fpm \
                                            php-mbstring \
                                            php-xdebug \
                                            -y
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install iputils-ping \
                                            net-tools \
                                            telnet \
                                            certbot \
                                            -y
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install npm -y
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install  vim  -y
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive npm i -g n
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive npm i -g node-sass
WORKDIR /var/www

# Xdebug Don't forget update your local ip address into xdebug.ini
# More info is here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J77iuOpnUm4
RUN rm /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/xdebug.ini
COPY xdebug.ini /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/xdebug.ini
COPY xdebug.ini /etc/php/7.2/fpm/xdebug.ini
RUN echo "zend_extension="`find /usr/lib/php -iname 'xdebug.so'` >> 
/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini

RUN echo "xdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1" >> 
/etc/php/7.2/fpm/xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1" >> /etc/php/7.2/mods- 
available/xdebug.ini
# End xdebug


RUN mv /var/www/html /var/www/public
RUN rm /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
RUN useradd -u 911 -U -d /config -s /bin/false abc && \
      usermod -G users abc
ADD ./000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available
ADD ./atrun.sh /var

EXPOSE 80
CMD sh /var/atrun.sh
```

Все нормально работает, но когда я через artisan генерирую модели или миграции, то они получаются с правами рута и я от своего пользователя на хост машине не могу их редактировать. Можно конечно всякий раз при создании менять файлам права, но это слишком жестко. Есть ли какое либо изящное решение для этой проблемы? Я погуглил и нашел совет создать другого пользователя. Создал, но это не принесло никакого толку. Еще что то говорили про дата-контейнеры, но я не понял, как это работает в данном случае.
P.S. Не советуйте мне использовать laradock. Я все хочу собрать руками.

Comment: вы выполняете artisan команды из-под контейнера?

Comment: Да, все верно. На хосте у меня в PHPStorm открыт проект, где я получаю файлы с рутовыми правами.

Answer (score 1):

Все верно, поскольку в докер-контейнера пользователь `root`, а на Вашей машине - другой.

Я не увидел у Вас в dockerfile директивы [VOLUME](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume), которая позволяет *подключить* в Ваш докер-контейнер указанную папку.

Соответственно - подключаете Вашу папку с проектом в контейнер и уже в ней (папке на диске) выполняете artisan-команды, которые будут создавать файлы из-под Вашего пользователя.

---

Почитайте про docker-compose и в целом про философию Docker-containers.

Вы в одном контейнере пытаетесь развернуть ВСЕ окружение, как будто Вы работаете с виртуальной машиной. Докер же говорит, что Вы должны для *каждого* элемента Вашего окружение использовать отдельный контейнер (apache + database + cache server + project - это все разные контейнеры) и линковать их между собой.

**UPD**. Вы также можете получать доступ к файлам, созданным в контейнере запустив контейнер от вашего пользователя:

1. Получить ID вашего пользователя - `id` или `echo $UID` (в терминале)
2. Запустить контейнер из-под Вашего пользователя - `docker run --user <id>`

Более автоматизированный вариант этого решения описан [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696676/set-docker-image-username-at-container-creation-time).

Comment: VOLUME там нет. Я использую -v при запуске. То есть, вы имеете ввиду, что мне нужно локально поставить php и запускать artisan у себя на хосте? По-моему я вас не правильно понял. Я понимаю философию докер, но php и apache вещи, связанные довольно тесно. Поэтому я решил установить их на одном контейнере. А дб будет отдельно.

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak это скорее я Вас не правильно понял - обновил ответ

Comment: А, то есть я могу указать тут своего пользователя на хосте? Я думал, что --user это указание, от какого пользователя в контейнере стартовать все процессы (ну, то есть, при создании контейнера  мы же можем создавать пользователей). А Вы говорите, что эта команда позволяет запускать от текущего пользователя ХОСТА. Я попробую, спасибо большое!!!

Comment: Не, не работает. http://joxi.ru/J2b8GnqTXwQN9r В общем я нашел такой выход из этой ситуации. При создании контейнера, я создам пользователя с такими же uid/gid, как у моего хостового пользователя. Далее, я запущу контейнер, как обычно. Он запустится от рута. Я запущу все службы (php-fpm, nginx ...) потом просто при помощи su <user> переключусь на созданного пользователя и буду работать. Кривое решение, но лучше я пока не знаю.